# Which date time object is the smartest that will take leap years etc. into consideration?

Tags: c#, datetime

If I do this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

And then:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Year, ..).AddDays(1);
```

It will take into consideration leap years and anything else that might be an issue with dates :)

I can't recall but I know .net 4 or 3.5 has new date time objects.

Comment: Yes `DateTime` will take care of leap years and all other nuances involved.

Comment: What's your question? AFAIK there's no new date time in .NET recently. SQL Server on the other hand has a few new ones in SS2008

Comment: Are you looking for [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)?

Comment: you can even do `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays (1)` - but I don't understand your question... please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save Jon Skeet from having to advertise his own project:

- [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)

Noda Time is a .NET library designed to simplify the correct handling of dates and times in the .NET environment. It is based on Joda Time, the industry standard date and time handling library for Java

Answer (score 1):

The **DateTime.AddYears()** method does consider leap years.